# What to do with the [data] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I’m not sure what the [data](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) tag means (currently used on 13 questions).

Almost any software works with *data* in some way, so I think it’s not a useful tag unless it gets a narrow definition (+ a tag wiki excerpt).

What to do? Get rid of the tag? Define it?

Comment: Perhaps it's meant to represent `data-sets`, although not all tagged questions use it that way; hence the ambiguity

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a meta-tag to me. From a quick look, none of the questions using it would make less sense without it:

- [database](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database)+[data](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data): what a surprise: a database uses... what?
- [backup](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup)+[recovery](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery)+[data](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data): wow. Anything else to backup/recover?

And so on. OK, in some cases it looks more useful (sql+comparison+data to make clear one isn't after structure or statement comparison). But a tag named [data](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) has a misleading side-effect as well: some might think they can ask for data – questions like those belonging to [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

**Conclusion:** I'd say we should kill it.

Comment: Burninate it? or just delete it?

Comment: At least remove it. I just re-checked: it's still the same 13 questions, and I see none of them that couldn't live without it. Looks really redundant to me – as described in my answer. If we remove it from all those questions, the system will auto-delete it after a while.